# list: Remove the indent at the beginning of subsequent (non-labeled) lines of each list item

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, itemize

In list environments like `itemize` and `enumerate`, the default spacing always put some extra indent at the beginning of each line *without* a label (i.e., bullets or numbers) such that the text starts at the exact same place where the text in a line *with* label starts. For example, in the following figure, "iscing elit" is aligned with "Lorem ipsum", not with "tincidunt" in the paragraph following the list.

[image]

**How can I remove this extra indent, so that, for example, "iscing elit" is aligned with "tincidunt", or whatever default the outside environment specifies for a line that does not start a paragraph?** I don't not have a strong preference for how the first lines of additional paragraphs inside a list item (e.g., "Donec quam" at the beginning of the second paragraph inside item (i)) should behave in terms of alignment, as long as it makes aesthetic sense. For example, I am fine with "Donec quam" being aligned with "Nullam".

At the same time, I also want to be able to use the `enumerate` or the `enumitem` package so I can change the label format (roman numbers, etc.) The code for the MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
    \item Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, 
    arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
\end{enumerate}

Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. 
Vivamus elementum semper nisi.

Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what you ask, simply use the `wide` option. Here are two variants:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(i), wide, parsep =0pt]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
    \item Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
    arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
\end{enumerate}

Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
Vivamus elementum semper nisi.

Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.

\begin{enumerate}[(i), wide, listparindent=0pt, parsep =0pt]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
    \item Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
    arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
\end{enumerate}

Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
Vivamus elementum semper nisi.

Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There are many parameters  associated with list making environments, as described in Section C.5.3 of the LaTeX User Guide and Reference Manual (pp. 166-168).  The `enumitem` package gives a convenient way to access them directly for your list, by way of optional argument.

The parameters relevant here are `\leftmargin` which is the overall alignment of the items, and `\itemindent`, which is the indentation (not counting the label) of the 1st line of the `\item`.

The indent of "Donec quam" type paragraphs are set with the additional parameter (not shown below) `listparindent=\parindent`, for example.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=30pt]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
    \item Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, 
    arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
\end{enumerate}

Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. 
Vivamus elementum semper nisi.

Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to set these parameters for the whole document at once? Is 30pt the default or recommended value for `itemindent`? Is the user guide you mentioned [this book by Leslie Lamport](https://www.amazon.com/LaTeX-Document-Preparation-System-2nd/dp/0201529831/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1475172005&sr=1-1&keywords=latex+User+Guide+and+Reference+Manual)?

Comment: @FangJing Page 9 of the `enumitem` documentation (http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) shows `\setlist[enumerate]{...}` to set global definitions.  I just grabbed 30pt out of the air...user preference, though you want it wide enough to handle your widest label width, which can vary greatly using roman numerals.  Yes, the LaTeX User guide is by Leslie Lamport.